# Cucumber can't find feature steps

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I'm doing an HelloWorld type of test using Cucumber for java.

I defined a Feature:

```
    Feature: To check that main tutorial course pages have loaded in TheTestRoom.com

    Scenario: To check that the WebDriver Cucumber tutorial main page has loaded
    Given I navigate to TheTestRoom.com
    When I navigate to Cucumber Tutorial page
    Then the page title should be visible
```

And this dummy implementation

```
    package step_definition;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.*;
    import cucumber.api.PendingException;

    public class myFirstStepDefinition {

            @Given("^I navigate to TheTestRoom\\ .com$")
            public void i_navigate_to_TheTestRoom_com() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
            }
            @When("^I navigate to Cucumber Tutorial page$")
            public void i_navigate_to_Cucumber_Tutorial_page() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
            }
            @Then("^the page title should be visible$")
            public void the_page_title_should_be_visible() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
            }
    }
```

Then I used to compile the step definition class and I used java to run the test, adding the compiled class path to the classpath

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java" -cp "C:\OutSystems\HelloWorld\dependency\*;C:\OutSystems\HelloWorld\step_definition\*" cucumber.api.cli.Main -p pretty -g step_definition C:\OutSystems\HelloWorld\feature\
```

But the output is as if the feature steps are not found:

```
    Feature: To check that main tutorial course pages have loaded in TheTestRoom.com

    Scenario: To check that the WebDriver Cucumber tutorial main page has loaded [90m# features.feature:3[0m
    [33mGiven [0m[33mI navigate to TheTestRoom.com[0m
    [33mWhen [0m[33mI navigate to Cucumber Tutorial page[0m
    [33mThen [0m[33mthe page title should be visible[0m

    1 Scenarios ([33m1 undefined[0m)
    3 Steps ([33m3 undefined[0m)
    0m0.000s


    You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

            @Given("^I navigate to TheTestRoom\\ .com$")
            public void i_navigate_to_TheTestRoom_com() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
            }
            @When("^I navigate to Cucumber Tutorial page$")
            public void i_navigate_to_Cucumber_Tutorial_page() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
            }
            @Then("^the page title should be visible$")
            public void the_page_title_should_be_visible() throws Throwable {
                    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
                    throw new PendingException();
            }
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: have you compiled `myFirstStepDefinition` class?

Comment: yes I did. I used javac to compile the java class and included the .class file in the java classpath "C:\OutSystems\HelloWorld\step_definition\*"

I have a isolated test env for this with a batch file that does the job if it helps troubleshooting

Comment: Can you paste complete output please?

Comment: @CarlosSousa Guessing but the classpath should not include the "step_definition" part in the second classpath option. Basing this on the assumption that there is only one "step_definition" folder instead of two in the heirarchy.

Comment: @EugeneS: just edit the post to get the full error

Comment: @Grasshopper: you're absolutely right. I just need to add the root dir for the class path. the remaining path was the package structure and it can be there. Can you right a post so, I mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing but the classpath should not include the "step_definition" part in the second classpath option. Basing this on the assumption that there is only one "step_definition" folder instead of two in the heirarchy.

Comment: you're absolutely right. I just need to add the root dir (...\HelloWorld) for the class path. the remaining path (...\step_definition\) is the package structure and it can not be there.